# Which is more reliable? Writing an unchanged configuration to disk or leaving existing configuration alone?

Tags: filesystems, hard-drive

I noticed that our code is writing our configuration files to disk every time the program exits, even if the configuration has not been altered. It takes less than 0.25 seconds to write out all the configuration so the user's don't actually notice any delay on close.

However we are trying to figure out which is more reliable over the long term. 
  Reliable is reading the exact same bits as were written.
  Long-term would be running the program 0 to 10 times a day for 3 years.

We are definitely not experts in disk drive performance, so any clues as to where to look for answers would be appreciated.

Comment: why would the configuration details change in between read and write? If the config cannot change on disk between read and why? what would be the benefit of writing the same information back?

Comment: RAID controller? Hardware configuration? OS?

Answer (score 1):

If something happens at the wrong moment while overwriting, the configuration file could be destroyed or lost. This (with today's filesystems microscopical) risk doesn't exist if nothing is written.

Comment: Actually, this is why programmers with any sense don't just overwrite critical files without making a copy first, or keeping a "last good config" around.  No need to worry about write corruption when you make sure to hold onto the last file that actually worked.

Comment: Yes, but the renaming is also a (microscopic) risk. If there are changes, keeping the old one around is just common sense. But _only_ replace if there are changes (so that if you keep, say, 5 worth of old ones, you don't get just 5 copies of the same).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reinventing the wheel?

You use what has been used since before I was born - a bit or boolean flag when a change is made to the configuration to indicate that there are changes to write to disk.  There's even a name for this, the ["dirty bit"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_bit) or "dirty flag" (and it happens in memory, no disk write required).